# Discord.js | How do I make a command that adds to an array variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so I tried to make a command that adds to an array (and also prints it / say it). However, I don't know how to do that.
Here's my code:

```js
const ALLANG = []

let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
let cmd = messageArray[0];
let args = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(' ')+1);

if(cmd === (prefix + "translate")) {
        message.channel.send(`All the available language: ${ALLANG} /* English, Spanish*/`)
      }


if(cmd === (prefix + "translateToENG") {
// Here i want to add "English" to the variable

translate(args, {to : 'en'}).then(englishTranslated => {
        message.channel.send(englishTranslated)
    }).catch(err => {
        message.channel.send('An error has occupied')
        console.log(err)
    })
  
}


if(cmd === (prefix + "translateToSpanish")) {
       // Here add "Spanish" to variable too


    translate(args, {to : 'es'}).then(spanishTranslated => {
        message.channel.send(spanishTranslated)
    }).catch(err => {
        message.channel.send('An error has occupied')
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Sorry for my bad English, but Thank you if you helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will reword your question as:

> How to append an element to an array, and display that array as a string

For your context - `ALLANG.push("English")` will work fine. This 'pushes' an element to the end of the array, modifying it.

Also, in these lines:

```js
if(cmd === (prefix + "translate")) {
        message.channel.send(`All the available language: ${ALLANG} /* English, Spanish*/`)
      }
```

Since you're `toString()`ing an array (by forcing the array expression into the context of a string), the default conversion would be something like `English,Spanish`, which, in my opinion, is a bit ugly. Instead, you could do:

```js
message.channel.send(`All the available languages: ${ALLANG.join(", ")}`)
```

which joins all the individual elements with `,`

Theoretically, it should then output
`English, Spanish`, which looks a bit more clean :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `ALLANG` is an *array*: (`const ALLANG = [];`) and not a *string*, `ALLANG += 'English'` will not work. If you want to insert it at a new *array index*, use:

```js
ALLANG[ALLANG.length] = 'English';
```

If you `console.log()` ALLANG out after this, it should show:

```js
['English']
```

**Do the same for the Spanish and others.**

Else if you want `ALLANG` to be a string, declare it as:

```js
var ALLANG = '';
```

Then you can use your code for string concatenation, or:

```js
ALLANG += 'English';
```

Comment: I wanted to insert it at the end, but `[0]` works too.

Comment: your method is a bit unnecessary as JavaScript already provides a method to push elements to the end of the array - see `Array.prototype.push()`

Also, your solution with the string will not work as you are constantly reassigning a value to that string, but declare it as `const`. 

In my opinion, `Array#join()` will be much more convenient and ensure that they don't have to mess with mutable data types